# Custom Solr analyzers not being used during indexing

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a bunch of PDF files on my machine which I want to index in Solr. For this purpose, I have created a schema file with custom field types and user-defined fields.

Given below are the fields and copyFields in my `schema.xml`:

```
<field name="id" type="custom01" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
<field name="_text_" type="custom02" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="fileEx" type="custom03" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

<copyField source="id" dest="fileEx"/>
```

The `id` field will contain the actual path of the indexed file. I plan to copy this value into `fileEx` and save just the extension of the file in the field using the custom analyzer as given in the field definition.

The following are my custom fieldType definitions:

```
<fieldType name="custom01" class="solr.TextField"> <!-- Dummy fieldType -->
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^$"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="custom02" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\.([^.]*$)" group="0"/>
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\." replacement=""/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I tried to index the files using this schema, the contents of the `id` field were just copied into `fileEx` without any analyzing done. Both `id` and `fileEx` had the same value. I used the analyzer tab in the SolrUI to see if my fieldTypes actually work and found that they work as expected.

But for some reason, the analyzers don't seem to be running properly while indexing actual documents.

So, at this point I am stuck and frustrated. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you're asking why the text returned from a hit hasn't changed? The text returned is the value before processing, not the tokenized contents of the field. You will not see any change in the value returned by changing the analyzer. This is required to make things like highlighting work properly.

If you want to change the text before it arrives in a field, use [an update processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors).

Comment: To clarify, my problem is that when I index a file, it is indexed something like this:

`id:C:\Users\User01\Downloads\test.pdf`

`fileEx:C:\Users\User01\Downloads\test.pdf`

But, what I want is:

`id:C:\Users\User01\Downloads\test.pdf`

`fileEx:PDF`

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the changes that the analyzer makes will not shown when you browse the index using `localhost:8983/.../browse`.

Comment: @Stack-Boi Yup. The browse interface will just show the stored text, not the processed tokens. The analysis page will show what actually happens behind the scene in token generation and matching.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! One final question. Is there a way to achieve what I want using an update processor. Is there an update processor that uses regex patterns?

Comment: You could probably use the [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html), or there's a ScriptUpdateProcessor (now prefixed with Stateless IIRC) that allows you to write your update processor as javascript code.