# Manipulate field value of copy-field in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I have a simple string "PART_NUMBER" value as a field in solr. I would like to add an additional field which places that value in a URL field. To do this, I created a new field type, field, and copy field

```
"add-field-type": {
    "name": "endpoint_url",
    "class": "solr.TextField",
    "positionIncrementGap": "100",
    "analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": {
            "class": "solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"
        },
        "filters": [
            {
                "class": "solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory",
                "pattern": "([\\s\\S]*)",
                "replacement": "http://myurl/$1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"add-field": {
    "name": "URL",
    "type": "endpoint_url",
    "stored": true,
    "indexed": true
},
"add-copy-field":{ "source":"PART_NUMBER", "dest":"URL" }
```

As some of you probably guessed, my query output looks like

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "PART_NUMBER": "ABCD1234",
    "URL": "ABCD1234",
    "_version_": 1645658574812086272
}
```

Because the endpoint_url fieldtype only modifies the index. Indeed, when doing my analysis, I get

```
http://myurl/ABCD1234.jpg
```

My question: Is there any way to apply a tokenizer or filter and feed it back in to the field value? I would prefer this output when returning the result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "PART_NUMBER": "ABCD1234",
    "URL": "http://myurl/ABCD1234.jpg",
    "_version_": 1645658574812086272
}
```

Is this possible to do in Solr?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was posted here:
[Custom Solr analyzers not being used during indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301371/custom-solr-analyzers-not-being-used-during-indexing?rq=1)

I need to use an Update Processors In order to change the field value before analysis. The process can be found here:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/update-request-processors.html